# Cannot find Support Package in Android SDK Manager

Tags: android

I need the Support Package jar file.
I opened the page http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html#Downloading and do as they said:

1. Launch the SDK and AVD Manager.
2. From Eclipse, you can select Window > Android SDK and AVD Manager.
   Or, launch SDK Manager.exe from the / directory (on Windows
   only) or android from the /tools/ directory.
3. Expand the Android Repository, check Android Support package and
   click Install selected.

But my SDK manager is updated and there is no 'Android Repository' anymore and i cannot find Android Support Package. 
[image]

Please give me any advice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's actually the <kbd>Android Compatibility package</kbd>. It's just a label error.

Comment: Thats odd - under Extras all I have is Google USB Drivers... How do I get that compatibility package to even show up?

Answer (score 0):

After installing API 16, I guess it's called as **Android Support Library**, and below is the path where the required library files are present:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk-windows\android-compatibility\v*`